# Wonky table on "Select your next badge"

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

On main and meta - table overhangs the window:

[image]

Comment: Seems like the search bar is too long and is being pushed to a new line, causing everything below the bar to be pushed one line down.

Comment: Sigh. _This_ issue again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. The issue arose because the search input field was given a size that fit exactly when using a sans-serif font like Arial. If a font is used which has wider letterforms, it breaks. I've shortened the width for the input field. This will be corrected with the next production build.